# Facing error again in minikube renew certificate

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

When I run  kubectl command getting error is certificate expired

How to debug minikube errors?

kubectl get pods

Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems issue is related to an expired certificate

A Temporary workaround is to removes several files from the /var/lib/minikube/ directory, then reset the Kubernetes cluster and replace keys on the host. Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10122#issuecomment-758227950) which can be helpful to resolve your issue

If the issue is not yet resolved try running the command `minikube delete` and then delete the local Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @Paul Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further

Comment: Restarts helped me!